# ¿Cómo acceder a una variable que esta dentro de una función ( JS)?

Tags: javascript

Hola buen día me serviría de mucho que me ayudaran con lo siguiente:

```
    function A(){
    var  a = 'Hola';
}

console.log(a)
```

Asi de simple , poder acceder a la variable "var" y me la pueda imprimir en consola.
O como hacerla global para poder acceder a ella?
Gracias buen dia.

Comment: `var` no es un nombre válido para una variable pues es un identificador que por ejemplo se usa en JS para declarar variables

Comment: Las variables declaradas dentro de una función no son accesibles fuera. ¿Qué es lo que quieres hacer para necesitar esta funcionalidad?

Answer (score 1):

lo que sucede es que no estas invocando a tu funcion **A** para que asigne un valor a esa variable y la puedes acceder, podrias hacer algo como esto:

```js
function A(){
 a = 'Hola';
}
//invoco a mi funcion
A();
//muestro el resultado
alert(a);
```

Espero te sirva y suerte..!!

Answer (score 1):

Esta aclaración la hago antes de darte una solución:

Cada variable se declara de acuerdo a su alcance: si una variable es declarado de forma GLOBAL, y se le hace alguna asignación dentro de una función, podrás acceder sin ningún problema a esa variable ya que su alcance es global(obvio su valor va ser determinado si usas la variable antes o después de llamar a la función). En cambio si quieres usar una variable fuera de la función de la que fue declarado entonces no podrás hacerlo y mucho menos si la función ni siquiera fue llamado.

Ahora la posible solución:

Teniendo en cuenta que el alcance de una variable local se limita a la función a la que es declarada, lo que podrías hacer es declarar una variable global(osea fuera de la función) y luego dentro de la misma función asignarle el valor de la variable que quieres usar fuera. Algo así:

```
var aux=''; // variable global

function A(){
    var  a = 'Hola';
    aux = a; //asignamos a la variable global el valor de la variable local
}

console.log(aux); // imprimimos la variable global con el valor asignado(obvio después de llamar a la función)
```

Espero se haya entendido.

Answer (score 0):

Lo mejor sería que la función devuelva el valor que necesitas y luego llamar la función de la siguiente manera:

```
function A(){
   return 'Hola, soy un string y fui regresado por una funcion';
}

console.log(A());
```

Comment: esto en realidad no responde a la pregunta, pues la duda es como acceder al valor de una variable que existe dentro de una función y no que una función devuelva una cadena de texto contenida en ella

Answer (score 0):

Una manera de hacerlo seria de la siguiente manera, pero si necesitas acceder variables dentro de funciones, o las devuelves con return o creas "clases" con funciones prototipo

```
var A = function () {
    this.A = 'Hola';
}

console.log( (new A()).A )
```

Answer (score 0):

Para hacerla global definela fuera de la funcion, aunque es una practica desaconsejada:

```
var  a;
function A(){
a = 'Hola';
}

console.log(a)
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes declarar de forma global fuera de la función dónde después la vayas a utilizar, fijate como declaro número fuera de la función, después dentrod e la función le asigno el valor del input tipo text, pongo la función `parseInt()` para volverlo un valor numérico, a continuación indico que va a pasar a la función sumar(), en la función sumar declaro una variable `resultado` la cuál hace la suma de `numero + 12`, y lo imprimo en el cuerpo de la pagina, espero te funcione.

```js
var numero="";

function  obtenerValor(){

  numero = parseInt(document.getElementById('1').value);

sumar();
}

function sumar(){

   var resultado = numero + 12;

document.write('El resultado de la suma es: '+resultado);

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <form>
    <input type="text" id="1">
<button onclick="obtenerValor()">click</button>
  
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Prueba lo siguiente:

```
    function A(){
     a = 'Hola';
     return a;
}

console.log(A());
```

Al llamar a la función y no pasarle parametros no puedes extraer a la variable "a". Lo que le dices es que te devuelva con `return a` el valor de "a". Después en `console.log` llamas a la función `A()` y no a la variable "a" para que te de el valor.